# Throwing the error: Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies. Any fixes?

Tags: flutter, xcode, cocoapods

Downloaded CocoaPods 3.2.2 using homebrew last week now my IOS simulator won't launch after adding google_sign_in: ^5.4.2, sign_in_with_apple: ^4.0.0, and flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0 dependencies. I'm not sure how to debug this error should as my CocoaPods seems to be up to date?